# How do I load the gender from the database and make it pre-selected in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, forms, laravel-blade

I'm trying to show the user what type of gender they currently have selected. (It's in dutch, Geslacht = Gender)

Here's the code:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm">
    <div class="form-group text-muted">                                         
      <label for="name">Geslacht:</label>                                         
      <select class="custom-select">                                             
        <option selected value="{{Auth::user()->geslacht}}">Kies een optie</option>
        <option value="1">Mannelijk</option>                                             
        <option value="2">Vrouwelijk</option>                                             
        <option value="3">Zeg ik liever niet</option>                                         
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
```

[image: Text is in dutch]

If you know how I might fix this please let me know ;)

Comment: appreciate if the answer is good for you to upvote .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <option value="1" @if(Auth::user()->geslacht == 1) selected @endif>Mannelijk</option>
 <option value="2" @if(Auth::user()->geslacht == 2) selected @endif>Vrouwelijk</option>   
 <option value="3" @if(Auth::user()->geslacht == 3) selected @endif>Zeg ik liever niet</option>
```

You can check in the option like this and if matched value then you can select it

Answer (score 0):

There is no other option than to check for each possible variable

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm">
    <div class="form-group text-muted">                                         
      <label for="name">Geslacht:</label>                                         
      <select class="custom-select">                                             
        <option disabled >Kies een optie</option>
        <option @if(Auth::user()->geslacht == 1) selected @endif value="1">Mannelijk</option>                                             
        <option @if(Auth::user()->geslacht == 2) selected @endif value="2">Vrouwelijk</option>                                             
        <option @if(Auth::user()->geslacht == 3) selected @endif value="3">Zeg ik liever niet</option>                                         
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't sure what you want, but if you want selected option by user gender auth, you can try this.

```
    <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm">
    <div class="form-group text-muted">                                         
      <label for="name">Geslacht:</label>                                         
      <select class="custom-select">                                             
        <option>Kies een optie</option>
        <option {{Auth::user()->geslacht == 1 ? 'selected' : '' }}  value="1">Mannelijk</option>                                             
        <option {{Auth::user()->geslacht == 2 ? 'selected' : '' }}  value="2">Vrouwelijk</option>                                             
        <option {{Auth::user()->geslacht == 3 ? 'selected' : '' }}  value="3">Zeg ik liever niet</option>                                         
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
```